# How to find all in specific column and replace based on another worksheet column data?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have two worksheets, one generated automatically by another Macro I already have, this one generates data in a new WorkSheet called "SheetN" where N is a numerical value that depends on how many times this macro has been executed.

Then, in my PrincipalSheet I have something like:

| Column R |
| --- |
| User1; User2; User3; |
| User2; User4; |
| User2; User3; User5; User6; |

In my auto generated SheetN I have:

| Column B |
| --- |
| User3; |
| User2; |
| NAN |

I want to be able to iterate through SheetN column B until is empty and make a find all based on every row that is not NAN and then replace with "" in the PrincipalSheet:

| Column R |
| --- |
| User1; |
| User4; |
| User5; User6; |

So far I have an idea to do something like

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim max As Integer
    i = 1
    i = 20
    
    While i < max
        If IsNot IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NewSheet).Cells(2, i)) Then
            MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets(NewSheet).Cells(2, i)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    

End Sub
```

To retrieve the values from SheetN but this is not working, I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

In the code I admitted that in SheetN columnB you can have duplicate values.

```
Sub ReplaceUserWithBlank()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Principal")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("SheetN")
    Dim lRowColB As Long: lRowColB = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lRowColR As Long: lRowColR = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rngColB As Range: Set rngColB = ws2.Range("B2:B" & lRowColB)
    Dim rngColR As Range: Set rngColR = ws1.Range("R2:R" & lRowColR)
    Dim rngTemp As Range: Set rngTemp = ws2.Range("K2:K" & lRowColB)
    
    ' copy column B to temporary column 'K'
    rngColB.Copy rngTemp
    
    ' set range in column 'K'
    Set rngTemp = Range(rngTemp, rngTemp.End(xlDown))

    ' Remove dulipcates
    rngTemp.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        
    ' reset rngTemp
    Set rngTemp = ws2.Range("K2", ws2.[K2].End(xlDown))
    
    ' Replace with blank
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In rngTemp
        rngColR.Replace What:=rCell.Value, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Next rCell
            
    ' Trim and Clean
    For Each rCell In rngColR
        rCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(rCell.Value))
    Next rCell
    
    ' Clear temporary range 'K'
    rngTemp.Clear
End Sub
```